# Set named range however works with active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in vba and tried to code something helps my daily job
Copy filtered rows from different dynamic - number of inputs increases on daily basis -  workbooks and sheets and paste into another workbooks sheets
Part of my coding is to find last row without functions in named sheet of named workbook, use below code but doesnt work correctly...find the last row but NOT named / set range, but the range of open worksheet...named worksheet is open as well amongst others, but result I receive is refer the one opened in front of me...what could be the solution here?

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("name")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("name")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A:AF")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim templastrow As Long

        templastrow = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To templastrow
        If Cells(i, 3).HasFormula Or Not Cells(i, 3).HasFormula Then
            If (Cells(i, 3).Value) < 1 Then
                lastrow = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify the sheet every time you access a Range (`Cells` is a Range), else VBA will use the cells of the active sheet, eg `ws.Cells(i, 3).HasFormula`

Comment: `Cells()` is not qualified, and if you want it to be locked, you would need something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells()`, so when the macro is called from any workbook, the information is not relative to the currect active instance.

Comment: @FunThomas & Cyril many thx for your explanation, Cells substitute with Set rng and works my code in a proper manner...great support big tenk you